# How to compare the structure of two MS SQL databases?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need a free tool or some kind of tip/technique to compare the structure of two Microsoft SQL databases. Preferably MS SQL 2005.

The technique I tried to make work was generating scripts from both databases and then comparing the two files, but SQL Server generates objects in random order.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it's only free on trial for 14 days, but [redgate sql compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/index.htm) is pretty good and easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

I use this tool: http://www.codeplex.com/ScriptDB on my dev database.

Then I check all the files into svn and diff the files generated to see what needs to be changed in my live database. Works for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Visual Studio 2008 (Database Edition) you can use that to compare SQL schemas.

Note that SQL Server 2008 support requires an update:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=bb3ad767-5f69-4db9-b1c9-8f55759846ed&displaylang=en

Answer (score 1):

Ditto for [RedGate SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/index.htm)....I've used it extensively for very large and complex DBs and it did the trick every time.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [dbForge Schema Compare for SQL Server](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/schemacompare/). It's not a freeware, but has 30-days free trial period, 30-days guaranteed money-back, and also you have a possibility to get a free license - please visit [free license conditions page](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/get-free-license.html).

Answer (score 1):

I simply don't use SQL Server Management Services anymore. It's too archaic and slow for development and testing purposes.

I use [TOAD for SQL Server](https://www.quest.com/products/toad-for-sql-server/software-downloads.aspx) from Quest Software.

It has a Schema Compare feature that does a brilliant job comparing structures (you can also compare data!), and it provides a wizard to merge the differences between two databases as well. All of this GUI controlled without a single manual-line-of-code!

It is very GUI concentrated with very powerful database management tools, including a brilliant schema and database-data comparer.

**Disclosure:** no, I don't work for Quest, but I've used TOAD for over 10 years and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Server Schema Compare](http://www.xsql.com/download/sql_server_schema_compare/downloading/) is free for MSSQL Express and a 2 week trial for the full version.

Answer (score 0):

This script (taken from [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/183991/14815)) can be used to do it in a crude way:

```
set nocount on;
-- Set the two variables newmodel and oldmodel to the appropriate database names and execute the script

declare @newmodel varchar(50), @oldmodel varchar(50);

Set @newmodel = '[NewModel to Compare]';
set @oldmodel = '[OldModel to Compare]';


Declare @Temp table (TABLE_SCHEMA varchar(40), TABLE_NAME varchar(40), COLUMN_NAME varchar(50), ORDINAL_POSITION int, IS_NULLABLE varchar(5), NullChange varchar(5), Comment varchar(50));

Declare @script varchar(5000);


set @script = '
Select nc.TABLE_SCHEMA, nc.TABLE_NAME, nc.COLUMN_NAME, nc.ORDINAL_POSITION, nc.IS_NULLABLE, IIF(nc.IS_NULLABLE <> oc.IS_NULLABLE, ''Yes'', ''No''), 
        IIF(oc.COLUMN_NAME IS NULL, convert(varchar(20), ''ADDED COLUMN''), convert(varchar(20), ''--'')) as Comment
    from {NEW}.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS nc
        LEFT join {OLD}.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS oc 
            on nc.TABLE_NAME = oc.TABLE_NAME and nc.COLUMN_NAME = oc.COLUMN_NAME
UNION ALL
    Select oc.TABLE_SCHEMA, oc.TABLE_NAME, oc.COLUMN_NAME, oc.ORDINAL_POSITION, oc.IS_NULLABLE, ''No'', ''DELETED COLUMN'' as Comment
    from {OLD}.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS oc
    where CONCAT(oc.TABLE_NAME, ''.'', oc.COLUMN_NAME) 
        not in (Select CONCAT(TABLE_NAME, ''.'', COLUMN_NAME) from {NEW}.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS)
';


Set @script = replace(@script, '{OLD}', @oldmodel);
Set @script = replace(@script, '{NEW}', @newmodel);

--print @script

Insert into @Temp
    exec(@script);

Select * from @Temp where Comment <> '--'
order by TABLE_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION, COLUMN_NAME;
go
```